# Image upload error 'Check the encoding type on the form.'

Tags: django, angular, image, django-rest-framework

In my project, i need to upload an image as an avatar for my players as shown in my **models.py :**

```
class Player(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, null=True, blank=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    selected = models.BooleanField(null = False, blank=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "#{}".format(
            self.number,
        )
```

I'm using angular to send my image using :

```
        <input
          type="file"
          (change)="onNewPlayerPhotoChanged($event)"
          accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpg"
        />
```

& in my typescript

```
  onNewPlayerPhotoChanged(event) {
    this.newPlayerPhoto = event.target.files[0];
  }
```

then on my submit button i got

```
  createPlayer() {
    this.newPlayer.selected = false;
    this.newPlayer.photo = this.newPlayerPhoto;
    this.newPlayer.post_id = parseInt(this.newPlayerPost, 10);
    this.playerService.create(this.newPlayer).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.getPlayerList();
        this.openNewModal = false;
        this.alertService.success('Joueur créé avec succès !');
        setTimeout(() => this.alertService.clear(), 2000);
      },
      error => {
        this.alertService.error(error);
        setTimeout(() => this.alertService.clear(), 2000);
      }
    );
  }
```

But i got the error : *photo: ["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."]*

Here is my **views.py : **

```
class PlayerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows Player to be viewed or edited.
    """

    parser_classes = [JSONParser]

    queryset = Player.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlayerSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, HasPermission, ]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse({"message":request.FILES}, status=200)
        print(request.FILES)
        print(request.data)
        photo = request.FILES['photo']
        firstname = request.data['firstname']
        lastname = request.data['lastname']
        number = request.data['number']
        tag = request.data['tag']
        color = request.data['color']
        selected = request.data['selected']
        post = request.data['post']
        Player.objects.create(photo=photo, firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname, number=number, tag=tag, color=color,
                              selected=selected, post=post)
        return HttpResponse({'message':"Player created"}, status=200)
```

& my **serializers.py :**

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post = PostSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    post_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='post', write_only=True, queryset=Post.objects.all(),)

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = '__all__'
```

I followed that tutorial *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-36YauTh4Ts* but he doesn't encouter that error,

if anyone could help, it would be much appreciated.
Thank you !

EDIT : I tried to use FileUploadParser & MultiPartParser as parser in my views but none of them would work either, FileUploadParser would return me an error saying the filename was needed and the MultiPartParser would return me an error syaing that he was receiving JSON.